# MySQL Join three tables return multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I have three tables: Let's call it CUSTOMER, LOG and REVIEW

The CUSTOMER table is:

```
id name
== ====
1  John
2  Jane
3  Mike
```

The LOG table is

```
id customer_id  created_at
== ===========  ==========
1  1            2015-06-10
2  1            2015-06-10
3  2            2015-06-11
4  1            2015-06-13
5  2            2015-06-15
6  1            2015-06-15
```

The REVIEW table is

```
id customer_id  created_at
== ===========  ==========
1  1            2015-06-10
2  2            2015-06-10
3  2            2015-06-11
4  1            2015-06-13
5  1            2015-06-15
6  1            2015-06-15
7  1            2015-06-18
```

What I wanted

```
CUSTOMER_ID NAME LOG_QTY REVIEW_QTY
=========== ==== ======= ==========
1           John 4       5
2           Jane 2       2
3           Mike 0       0
```

What I got:

```
CUSTOMER_ID NAME LOG_QTY REVIEW_QTY
=========== ==== ======= ==========
1           John 20      20
2           Jane 4       4
3           Mike 0       0
```

My query:

```
                       select CUSTOMER.ID, CUSTOMER.NAME,
 count(REVIEW.CUSTOMER_ID) as REVIEW_QTY,
    count(LOG.CUSTOMER_ID) as LOG_QTY
                         from CUSTOMER
                    left join REVIEW
                           on REVIEW.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID
                    left join LOG
                           on LOG.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID
                     group by CUSTOMER.ID
                     order by CUSTOMER.ID
```

Comment: Your expected results should match the data you see here. From what I see, Mike has no review or log qty.

Comment: My mistake. Editing to make it look correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your query without the `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`, you'll see what's happening:

```
select CUSTOMER.ID, CUSTOMER.NAME,
 REVIEW.CUSTOMER_ID as REVIEW_QTY,
 LOG.CUSTOMER_ID as LOG_QTY
from CUSTOMER
 left join REVIEW on REVIEW.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID
 left join LOG on LOG.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID
order by CUSTOMER.ID
```

This returns a row for each possible combination of rows with the same `CUSTOMER_ID` from the three tables (that's just what `INNER JOIN` does).  Then `COUNT` just counts 'em!

This should give you what you need:

```
select CUSTOMER.ID, CUSTOMER.NAME,
 (select count(*) from REVIEW where CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID) as REVIEW_QTY,
 (select count(*) from LOG where CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID)  as LOG_QTY
from CUSTOMER
order by CUSTOMER.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

What your query is doing is joining the reviews and logs on the customer, with no join condition between the two. This means you are creating a Cartesian product of each log with each review of a given customer (e.g. the 4 logs you expect for John multiplied by his 5 reviews explains the 20 you are getting).

One way to solve this is to perform a `group by` on the logs and on the reviews separately, in subqueries:

```
SELECT    c.id, c.name, review_qty, log_qty
FROM      customer c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   customer_id, COUNT(*) AS review_qty
           FROM     review 
           GROUP BY customer_id) r ON r.customer_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   customer_id, COUNT(*) AS log_qty
           FROM     log
           GROUP BY customer_id) l ON l.customer_id = c.id
ORDER BY  c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a complex query like this, I always recommend that you first break it up into pieces and place them back together.

For example, to get the counts per customer for an individual table, you can use the following aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS logCount
FROM log
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

You can do the same for review, and at the end outer join those results to the customer table to get their name. The reason you should use an outer join is because it's possible the user has no entries in the other tables. Because of that, you should use the `COALESCE()` function to replace null counts with 0:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COALESCE(l.logCount, 0) AS logCount, COALESCE(r.reviewCount, 0) AS reviewCount
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS logCount
  FROM log
GROUP BY customer_id) l ON l.customer_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS reviewCount
  FROM review
  GROUP BY customer_id) r ON r.customer_id = c.id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ed55/2) example using your sample data.