# How to show reviews per restaurant in php with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to show the amount of reviews for each restaurant.

I made 2 tables containing my data.

```
CREATE TABLE `restaurants` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reviews` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `slug` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'slug-test',
  `approved` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `review` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `img_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `restaurant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `review_text` text NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `restaurant_id` (`restaurant_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `reviews_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`) REFERENCES `restaurants` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am already showing my restaurants in a list.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE approved = 1 ORDER BY created_date DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
**HTML WITH MY VARIABLES**
}
```

This is how u currently show my reviews (hardcoded result in my restaurants table.

```
if ($reviews <= "0") {
echo "<a href='#' title='Write reviews'><p class='purple-def-color fz-12 mb-0'>write a review</p></a>";
} else if ($reviews > "1") {
echo "<p class='purple-def-color mb-0'>". $row['reviews'] ." reviews</p>";
} else {
echo "<p class='purple-def-color mb-0'>" . $row['reviews'] . " review</p>";
}
```

I tried to use a JOIN query but was not successful to show the amount of reviews in any way.

Comment: Which JOIN query did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: I tried to make something up that looks like SELECT colors.color, shapes.shape FROM colors JOIN shapes ON colors.id = shapes.color_id; But to be my php and mysql knowlegde ends there.

Comment: This might be the solution. But I'm not sure how to implement it to show the results: SELECT restaurant.*, count( reviews.restaurant_id ) FROM reviews LEFT JOIN restaurant ON restaurant.id=reviews.restaurant_id GROUP BY reviews.restaurant_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your table structure, you can get a review count for each restaurant by joining the `reviews` table, selecting the COUNT of reviews, and grouping by restaurant ID.

Grouping by restaurant allows you to get an [aggregate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) (e.g. [count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)) of the joined review records for each restaurant.

```
SELECT
    rs.*,
    COUNT(rv.`id`) as `reviewCount`
FROM `restaurants` rs
LEFT JOIN `reviews` rv
    ON (rv.`restaurant_id` = rs.`id`)
WHERE rs.`approved` = 1
GROUP BY rs.`id`
ORDER BY rs.`created_date` DESC;
```

Then, when you fetch the rows in PHP, you can reference each row's review count:

```
echo $row['reviewCount'];
```

---

To further demonstrate aggregate functions, here's an example of how to select the [average](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg), [minimum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min), and [maximum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) review score for each restaurant:

```
SELECT
    rs.*,
    COUNT(rv.`id`) as `reviewCount`,
    AVG(rv.`score`) as `reviewAverageScore`,
    MIN(rv.`score`) as `reviewMinScore`,
    MAX(rv.`score`) as `reviewMaxScore`
FROM `restaurants` rs
LEFT JOIN `reviews` rv
    ON (rv.`restaurant_id` = rs.`id`)
WHERE rs.`approved` = 1
GROUP BY rs.`id`
ORDER BY rs.`created_date` DESC;
```

Comment: This is just absolutely amazing. Thank you for this. I can learn a lot from this.

Comment: Tank you for the average score. I was just typing that question here. I will work on that. If it doesn't work out you will here me again :). Thank you you again.

Comment: So basically I can ad any items and calculation I want to select from the joined table? Can you also join a third table if needed?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what you're joining. You may need to group additional columns; here's an example: [Mysql three table join with aggregate columns and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706661/mysql-three-table-join-with-aggregate-columns-and-group-by). Depending on what you're aiming for, queries can get [a bit more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171361/mysql-join-three-tables-return-multiple-results).

Answer (score 1):

Try a left join:

`$query = 'SELECT * FROM restaurants LEFT JOIN reviews on reviews.restaurant_id = restaurants.id'`

A left join returns all records from the left table (restaurants), and the matched records from the right table (reviews)

Comment: Yes. I was trying with SELECT restaurant.*, count( reviews.restaurant_id ) FROM reviews LEFT JOIN restaurant ON restaurant.id=reviews.restaurant_id GROUP BY reviews.restaurant_id. But I'm not sure how to show the results inside of my code as I am already fetching another query.

Comment: `SELECT restaurant.*, count( reviews.restaurant_id ) as numReviews FROM reviews LEFT JOIN restaurant ON restaurant.id=reviews.restaurant_id GROUP BY reviews.restaurant_id` And use `$row['numReviews']`